# To give some example where $x_n\rightarrow x$, $y_n\rightarrow y$ weakly but $(\langle x_n, y_n\rangle)_{n}$ is not convergent:

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let us $X$ an vector space with inner product. To give some example where $x_n\rightarrow  x$, $y_n\rightarrow y$ weakly both but $(\langle x_n,y_n\rangle)_{n}$ is not convergent:

Well the excercise has a following hint: Consider $(e_1,e_2,\ldots)$ and $(e_2,e_2,e_4,e_4,\ldots)$ where $e_i$ are orthonormal.

Then for me, if we choose $x_n=(e_1,e_2,\ldots)$ and $y_n=(e_2,e_2,e_4,e_4,\ldots) $ we have $(\langle x_n,y_n\rangle)= (0,1,0,1, \ldots)$ so this sequence is not convergent.

My problem is understanding why the sequences above are weakly convergent, and which is their limit respectively.

For example $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ means that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $f\in X'$ (Dual of $X$-all linear continuous functions from $X\to \mathbb C$)

So, please i would like to know if i need to choose a particlar functional $f$ that show me what is the limit $x$?

I found that in $l^{\infty}$ the weak limit for $e_n$ is $0$ and their proof was by contradiction, but what is the tool that permit to find the weak limit of any sequence?

In my excercise do not say anything else, so i do not know who are the limit $x$ and $y$ respectively. Please, i want to know how to star when the problem say something as: Given the sequence $z_n$ calculate their weak limit? Please i will appreciate any hint. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your example: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $e_n$ an orthonormal sequence in $H$. Then $e_n$ must converge to zero weakly. This is due to Bessel's inequality, which states for every vector $x$ in $H$ and orthonormal sequence $e_n$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |(x|e_n)|^2 \leqslant \lVert x \rVert^2.$$
This implies that for each $x$, we must have $|(x|e_n)|^2 \to 0$, as the series couln't be convergent otherwise.

Proof of Bessel's inequality in prehilbert spaces:

Let $X$ be a prehilbert space and $e_n$ an orthonormal sequence in it. Let $x$ be an arbitrary vector in $X$. Let's define the following quantities:
$$\alpha_n := (x | e_n) \quad \text{and} \quad s_n := \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k e_k.$$

Then, using simple algebra:
$$\lVert x - s_n \rVert ^2 = \lVert x \rVert ^2 - (x | s_n) - (s_n|x) + \lVert s_n \rVert^2$$

From Pythagorean theorem, we also have that

$$\lVert s_n\rVert^2 = \sum_{k=0}^n |\alpha_k|^2,$$

and rewriting the "mixed" term

$$(x|s_n) = \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha^*_n(x|e_n) = \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha^*_n\alpha_n= \sum_{k=0}^n |\alpha_n|^2 \in \mathbb{R},$$
implying also $(x|s_n)=(s_n|x)$.

Putting it together,
$$\lVert x - s_n \rVert ^2 = \lVert x \rVert^2 - \sum_{k=0}^n |\alpha_k|^2 \geqslant 0,$$
proving the required inequality.

Comment: In my case $X$ is a vector space with inner product, is valid too? Thank you @Botond

Comment: @weymarandres Yes, I think. It only requires some algebra and the Pythagorean theorem, which does not need the completeness.

Comment: thank you @Botond

Comment: @weymarandres you're welcome. Nevertheless, a Hilbert space argument would work anyway. If $X$ is your prehilbert space, you can complete it to a Hilbert space $H$. In that Hilbert space, $(e_n | x) \to 0$ for all $x \in H$. You can restrict it to only $x \in X$ as well, to get what you wanted. If you define the weak convergence with linear functionals, you can use Riesz's Representation theorem in the Hilbert space $H$ to get weak convergence in $H$, which should hold in $X$ as well due to similar arguments.

Comment: Now is clearer for me,  i learning to how complete to a Hilbert space, if perhaps has some reference to learn that subject, i will appreciate so much. Thank you again @Botond

Answer (score 1):

You can take for $x_n= \sin (nx)$ and for $y_n = \sin (nx)$ if $n$ is even and $y_n= \cos (nx)$ when $n$ is odd. Now, for any function $f$ in $L^2[0,2\pi]$ integral of product $fx_n$ or $fy_n$ tends to $0$, yet integral of $x_ny_n$ jumps between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thank you Dear @Salcio !! i understand your example. In general, how we can see the possible weak limit? best

Comment: Weak limits are $0$ since Fourier coefficients of any $L^2$ functions tend to $0$

Comment: Always the limit is $0$? Sorry perhaps is my english. Thank you again @Salcio

Comment: Yes for any function $f$ in $L^2[0,2\pi]$ integral of $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)sinnx dx$ tends to $0$. The same holds for $cosnx$.

Comment: In the hint of my question, do you know who is $x$ and $y$? Thanks

Comment: They tend weakly to $0$, in words $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Thank you dear @Salcio. My last question is: Always in any space with inner product the weak limit has to be $0$. Sorry for many questions!!

Comment: No, for example since $sin nx$ tends weakly to $0$ then $sin nx + 1$ will tend weakly to $1$. That is $1$ here is a constant function which is always $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!